# Sentry overloading my PHP server

Tags: php, sentry

I am working on a legacy PHP application which wasn't well tested over time and which continuously generates PHP errors of all types.

I've set up Sentry in order to log all errors to avoid dealing with logging on the server and going through the log files.

However, as soon as I set up the error reporting to be sent for E_ALL. Sentry bottlenecks the server and crashes requests to the server.

I am trying to figure out how I would setup enough resources to handle all the PHP errors being handled by Sentry.

Comment: Do you need to log all of the errors? You can just setup the necessary ones.

Comment: Probably not, but this legacy app is particularly error prone so I'd like to have a good idea of where all the errors are caused.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a little crazy approach. If the errors are so many then why don't you:

1. Create your own error handler - there are many php example that you can use
2. Handle the errors in your own way by saving info that is really needed
3. Now comes the "crazy part" - save the data in memcache. Instead of heavy I/O operations or overwhelming MySQL you can setup memcache and let say once a 5 minutes to flush the data in log file or somewhere else (you can setup this flush period according to the app load). You can even create a cron job for the  flushing.

Comment: You can also probably skip memcache and save data directly into MySQL table with Memory engine. Then flush data from memory table into persistent table. This way would need one less system for this to work

Answer (score 1):

While you have this many errors, I'd recommend you start with less than E_ALL until you've fixed the most critical errors. Try:

> error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);